# JS :: First Class Functions :: Parameter Value Confusion

Tags: javascript, first-class-functions

I do not understand how the parameter of the first class function, "number", has the value it does.

I have been mulling over this problem for a couple of days and I am not making any progress in my thinking. There is no error code as this is perfectly valid JS.

This example code is from the book Eloquent JS (http://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/05_higher_order.html#c_chCFkdNvRH 2nd ed).

```js
// definition
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}

//vars
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;

// implemented function
forEach(numbers, function(number) {
  sum += number;
});

//output
console.log(sum);
// → 15
```

I dont understand why 'number' is not considered undefined. Shouldn't the parameter be 'numbers[i]' or 'numbers', which references the actual array?

Comment: `array[i]` is provided to the argument `number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `forEach` declaration you are passing a function reference as a second argument which you are calling and passing a value from the array:

```
function forEach(array, action) <--- action is a function reference
```

`action` is called like `action(array[i])`, with a value from array.

Now when `forEach` is called the value for the `action` is an actual function object.

You can visualize it as such:

```
action = function(number) {
  sum += number;
}
```

`action` is expected to take a argument which is called with a value from an array, so the `number` parameter is actually that value from the array `array[i]`

Answer (score 0):

If we want to unravel what this code is doing, we can rewrite it without using a function that accepts another function as a parameter. This process of unraveling is called [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion). Here, we are inlining `forEach()`:

```js
// vars
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;

// inlined forEach
var array = numbers;
var action = function(number) {
  sum += number;
};

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  action(array[i]);

// output
console.log(sum);
// → 15
```

We can unravel this code again by inlining `action()`:

```js
// vars
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;

var array = numbers;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  // inlined action
  var number = array[i];
  sum += number;
}

// output
console.log(sum);
// → 15
```

So in fact what's happening is we assign `numbers` to `array` and

```
function(number) {
  sum += number;
}
```

to `action`, then we assign `array[i]` to `number` when we call `action(array[i])`, which means the following code is equivalent, without using the extra variables:

```js
// vars
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  sum += numbers[i];

// output
console.log(sum);
// → 15
```

Of course, the point of `forEach()` is to avoid having to rewrite all of that logic each time we need to loop through an array and do something with each item.

Comment: Thank you for the indepth comment but I think that it is most fair to award based on the first answer that sufficiently addressed my question. However, based on your comment I now just gleaned a really great approach and I will be using inlining to splay all my future questions. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}
```

You define a function, okay and it has two arguments, one is an array and another is a callback. The argument `action` is a **callback** when you add parentheses around it `action(data)` and this data is sent to the callback function because you added parentheses around it.

```
forEach(numbers, function(number) { // here the number variable is array[i]
  sum += number; // now sum = 0 then you are doing the array[i] + the last value into the sum variable.
});
```

Hence you get sum as the sum of the array values.

To understand callback, take this basic snippet

```js
function hello(text,callback){
  callback(text,", World") // the first arg is text and the second is a string as "World"
}
hello("Hello", function(text,worldtext){
  console.log(text + worldtext) // Hello, world because we did text + worldtext
});
```

It takes the first argument and a callback where we can use to access the variable and do things with it.

Answer (score 0):

The basic summary is that there is a difference between a parameter and an argument.

Let's look at a function definition:

```
function addOne(amount) {
    console.log(amount + 1);
}
```

In this function, `amount` is a parameter, not an argument. The parameter is essentially just the variable name that will be referenced inside this function; it has no value on its own.

But then, we can call this function:

```
addOne(4);
```

Here, the argument is 4. The parameter is still `amount`. What happens is the argument 4 is bound to the parameter `amount` -- that is, `amount` "takes on" the value of 4 during this particular execution of the function.

So in your code, you're defining a function as follows:

```
function(number) {
  sum += number;
};
```

This function has no name, and it has a parameter: number. Only when the function is called (which it hasn't been yet) will `number` have a value. But luckily, you're passing this function on to `forEach`, which DOES call it with a value:

```
action(array[i]);
```

(Remember: in the `forEach` function, `action` is a parameter, and since you've called forEach with our anonymous function above as the argument, `action` will reference that function during this execution.)

Since the argument here is `array[i]`, and it corresponds to the anonymous function's parameter `number`, during this execution, the value of `number` will be set to the value of `array[i]`

I hope that clears things up for you :)